# How can I reflect a point about a line in Unity?

Tags: unity

I am drawing a line using the line renderer in the following way:

```
public class MyLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour {
LineRenderer lineRenderer;

public Vector3 p0, p1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
  lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
  lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;

  lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, p0);
  lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, p1);

}
```

}

From the image below, the line `P0P1` is known and so is point A. How can a point B, which is the reflection of A about the line `P0P1` be found?

[image]

Comment: Say, I notice you're defining your points as `Vector3`s, but a reflection across a line is not defined in 3 dimensions. We can reflect across a plane if we have a third point. Or, if your `Vector3`s are actually storing 2D vectors in the XY or XZ plane, then we can perform a reflection across the line in this plane - we just need to know which one you're using.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a cross-post of a question asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793217/how-can-i-reflect-a-point-about-a-line-in-unity). Cross-posting on Stack Exchange sites is not allowed. Please decide what Stack Exchange site will give you the best answer and ask only there. If you feel like it's gamedev, then please delete the question on SO and ping me here or flag the question for mod attention.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt the question can't be deleted from SO. I tried.

Comment: @Containment I understand. Unfortunately, I'll not reopen this one, but you have plenty of answers to it already so I don't think it's a big issue. I'd appreciate if you could delete those duplicate on SO that are not closed yet here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Form a unit vector in the direction of the line.
var lineDirection = (p1 - p0).normalized;

// Rotate the vector 90 degrees in the XY plane
// to get a vector perpendicular to the mirror line.
var perpendicular = new Vector3(-lineDirection.y, lineDirection.x, 0);
// If you're working in the XZ plane instead, it's
// (-lineDirection.z, 0, lineDirection.x)

// Take away a's perpendicular offset from this line, twice.
// Once to flatten a onto the line, and a second time to make b,
// an equal distance away on the opposite side of the line.
var b = a - 2 * Vector3.Dot((a - p0), perpendicular) * perpendicular;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. You also answered another question that I had in this solution

Comment: I'm glad! May I ask what the other question was?

Comment: How to move a point till it lies on a line