# How can I find the reflection of a point in a perpendicular line?

Tags: geometry

From the image below I know the positions `A` and `B`. How can I find positions `C` and `D` and the reflection (`Er`) of an object `E` in the line `CD`? I saw the solution in [How can I reflect a point about a line in Unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154400/how-can-i-reflect-a-point-about-a-line-in-unity) but I don't understand it enough to apply it in my case. Please note that I'm trying to achieve this in 2D.

[image]

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of the question you link, which already contains copy-and-paste ready code you can use in Unity. If you can clarify what it is about the linked question's answer you don't understand or is not working for you, we can focus on that specific issue, or improve that answer.

Comment: @DMGregory I guess it's the maths, I'm struggling to understand especially how the last line with `Vector3.Dot`. Maybe a diagram showing how works out would help.

Comment: @DMGregory please would you take a look at this for me if you can https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/160161/a-coroutine-to-rotate-one-point-around-another-by-a-given-angle-without-referrin

Comment: @DMGregory I am still trying to solve the above linked question. Please could you look at it for me if you get any spare time

Comment: Please do not repeatedly tag users if they haven't replied to you. The nature of StackExchange is that anyone can suggest answers, edits, etc, so you don't need to count on a particular user's input.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry about that. Well noted. I guess it's the frustration of trying to solve an issue for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with unity, but here's an answer in GLSL-like pseudocode.

```
vec2 a = ..., b = ..., e = ...;
vec2 center = (a + b) / 2; // the intersection of the two lines
vec2 n = a - center; // mirror normal
vec2 c = center + vec2(n.y, -n.x); // here I assume that the length of the mirror is
vec2 d = center + vec2(-n.y, n.x); //   equal to the distance between A and B
n = normalize(n);
float l = dot(n, e - center); // distance between CD and E
vec2 er = e - 2*l*n;
```

Comment: It's working, but you didn't use the result from you got from `c` and `d`

Comment: @TenOutOfTen You asked for positions of points C and D yourself. :P *"How can I find positions C and D and the reflection (Er)"*.

Comment: Okay, that's true. :) I thought their results were necessary for finding `Er`. May I ask, how will the solution change for points getting inflected along a line as shown in https://imgur.com/a/CUpFbie?

Comment: @TenOutOfTen It's simply `2*center - point`.